# ESXi 4.1 Do i need backup vmfs metadata files

Tags: backup, esxi

I've done a backup of the content of my datastore in order to move it from RAID 0 to RAID 5.

I've backup every files except vmfs file (.fbb.sf, .fdc.sf, .pbc.sf, .sbc.sf, .vh.sf).

Do i need those files for creating my new datastore ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you do not need those files. They are partition meta-data.

> Each resource type is managed by one of 4 system files which are
>   created during the file system bootstrap process:
>
> ```
> fbb.sf - file block bitmap.system file
> pbc.sf - pointer block cluster.system file
> sbc.sf - sub-block cluster.system file
> fdc.sf - file descriptor cluster.system file
> ```

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1001618